# Finding where a given number falls in a partition

Tags: python, data-partitioning

Suppose I have a sorted array of integers say

```
partition = [0, 3, 7, 12, 18, 23, 27]
```

and then given a value

```
value = 9
```

I would like to return the interval on which my value sits. For example

```
bounds = function(partition, value)
print(bounds)
>>>[7,12]
```

Is there a function out there that might be able to help me or do I have to build this from scratch?

Comment: A binary search will quickly return the needed bounds.  There are various binning functions that will do this, but I suspect that the extra set-up for that might be harder for others to read than the binary search.

Comment: Why the down votes? I realize this is probably silly for you Python wonks out there, but I am learning as I go for a project at work. This was a specific syntax question I had no familiarity with in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [numpy.searchsorted().](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) From the documentary:

> Find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.

```
import numpy as np
partition = np.array( [0, 3, 7, 12, 18, 23, 27] )
value = 9
idx = np.searchsorted(partition,value)
bound = (partition[idx-1],partition[idx])
print(bound)
>>>>(7,12)
```

The advantage of `searchsorted` is that it can give you the index for multiple values at once.

Comment: Your partition bound is wrong. Change it to `bound = (partition[idx-1],partition[idx])
`

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning Python on the fly at work, so this has been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

The [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html) is nice for doing this efficiently. It will return the index of the higher bound.

You'll need to do some error checking if the value can fall outside the bounds:

```
from bisect import bisect
partition = [0, 3, 7, 12, 18, 23, 27]
value = 9
top = bisect(partition, value)

print(partition[top-1], partition[top])
# 7 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def function(partition,value):
  for i in range(len(partition)):
  if partition[i]<value and partition[i+1]>value:
    print [partition[i],partition[i+1]]
 partition = [0, 3, 7, 12, 18, 23, 27,5,10]
 value=9
 function(partition,value)
```

Comment: This is not the optimal solution, since in worst-case, you'd need to touch every element at least once. If you're going to implement it yourself, you're better off doing binary search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm